# Why Apache IoTDB created multiple dataRegions for the same database settings in short period of time?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Why Apache IoTDB created multiple dataRegions for the same database settings in short period of time?

I am now using standalone version and all default configurations of Apache IoTDB. After startup, I created databases 1-6 and create, mount, and activate a template. Then, I insert a time series data to databases 1-6 respectively. I checked and see the dataRegions of 6 different databases have been created. However, when I insert data to databases 1-2, two new dataRegions of database 1-2 were created. I want to know that two dataRegions of the same database were created in a short period of time, is this reasonable? Why are two identical dataRegions created in the same databases in IoTDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is reasonable to create different dataRegion due to different tasks of inserting data in Apache IoTDB, since this can better distribute the write load. The dataRegions are not "identical" as you mentioned, since you can see the `regionID` using `show regions` command, which you should see to be different since the creation time is different.